# How to implement real time validation in Livewire 2?

Tags: laravel-livewire

Before I applied new livewire V2 programming style I had a form that was wired to a Model's individual properties.
To trigger the real time validation for fields, I used this in the component (e.g. name property):

```
public function updatedName(){
      $this->validate(['name' =>'required|max:127']);
}
```

name being a property of a Model named **Malt**.
My question is: how to modify this updatedName() function ?

I already understood that I should rename the function to updatedMaltName, thus I tried this.

```
public function updatedMaltName(){ 
  $this->validate(['name' =>'required|max:127']);
}
```

but it doesn't work. Instead it display an error "The name field is required" as soon as I type a char in the field (which is the opposite of what should happen), and never hide this error even if I empty the field.

I also tried this

```
public function updatedMaltName(){
      $this->validate(['malt.name' =>'required|max:127']);
    }
```

but this doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define your ruleset in a `$rules` property in your component-class.

```php
protected $rules = [
    'malt.name' => 'required|max:127',
];
```

You can now hook into the `updated()` method and `validateOnly()` on the field that was just now updated. This will now validate any fields being updated on your model, with the rulset defined in `$rules`.

```php
public function updated($property)
{
    $this->validateOnly($property);
}
```

The `$property` argument is the name of the field you are updating, so for example `malt.name`.

You can of course hook into the specific property you are updating, and validate only that field. This assumes you have a model in a property `$malt` that has a property `name` in it.

```php
public function updatedMaltName()
{
    $this->validateOnly('malt.name');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried both solutions but none of them works. When I type a char in the malt.name field, the updated function is called and dd($property) returns 'malt.name'. I also changed 127 with 1 and typed 2 or 3 chars but nothing happens. The protected $rules is set correctly. I probably miss something else.

Comment: I eventually made it out. I used a input-group component but I was not passing it the right porperties. 'name. instead of 'malt.name'

Comment: for the future people seeing this, if you wire your component with `wire:model.defer`, then livewire won't send updates to the component. So use `wire:model`  instead if you want to use live validating

Comment: @SühaBoncukçu That's exactly what `wire:model.defer` does, so that is the expected behavior. For those worried about making too many requests, you can limit them by using `wire:model.lazy` or introduce a slower debounce, `wire:model.debounce.500ms`. By using `wire:model.defer` the request is queued and sent when the next request is made, whenever that is.